# Deleting duplicates with hierarchy condition SQL Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, duplicates, hierarchy

I need to delete duplicates in a large database, but the rows to be deleted must be based on a hierarchy using either SQLite or Python Pandas. Is there a efficient way to relize this? preferably using python pandas dataframe but SQLite is also fine.

| ID | Text | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | text | Priority 3 |
| 2 | text | Priority 1 |
| 3 | text | Priority 2 |
| 4 | text 2 | Priority 3 |
| 5 | text 2 | Priority 2 |

should turn to this:

| ID | Text | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | text | Priority 1 |
| 5 | text 2 | Priority 2 |

Comment: Welcome! Let us know if you need to preserve the original index or not :)

Comment: This is not needed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['Text','Category'], ascending=[True,True])
df.groupby('Text')['Category'].first().reset_index()
```

Output:

| index | Text | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | text | Priority 1 |
| 1 | text 2 | Priority 2 |

Comment: Thank you! It kinda works, but what if there are more columns and the content of that column is different? I need the script to only compare the column "Text" to see if there are duplicates in that column.  And if yes, the row should be deleted based on priority.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar approach to @Drakax but using `drop_duplicates` instead of `groupby` and `first`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'Text': ['text', 'text', 'text', 'text 2', 'text 2'],
    'Category': ['Priority 3', 'Priority 1', 'Priority 2', 'Priority 3', 'Priority 2'],
})

df.sort_values(['Text','Category']).drop_duplicates('Text')
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid sorting when you can, use a `Categorical` to define the order of the priorities and get the index of the min per group:

```
# priorities in order
priorities = ['Priority 1', 'Priority 2', 'Priority 3']
# set up Categorical
df['Category'] = pd.Categorical(df['Category'], priorities, ordered=True)
# min per group 
df.loc[df.groupby('Text')['Category'].idxmin()]
```

Output:

```
   ID    Text    Category
1   2    text  Priority 1
4   5  text 2  Priority 2
```